# What makes multi-layer neural networks able to perform nonlinear operations?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, math, activation-functions, function-approximation

As I know, a single layer neural network can only do linear operations, but multilayered ones can.

Also, I recently learned that finite matrices/tensors, which are used in many neural networks, can *only represent linear* operations.

However, multi-layered neural networks can represent non-linear (even much more complex than being just a nonlinear) operations.

What makes it happen? The activation layer?

Comment: The very quick answer is; yes, nonlinear **activation functions** in between linear transformations (matrix multiplications) allow for the "total" to represent non-linear functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nonlinear relations between input and output can be achieved by using a nonlinear activation function on the value of each neuron, before it's passed on to the neurons in the next layer.